# Change Object properties without defining in a seperate class

Tags: java, object, properties

Hi I've run into an issue in one of my programs which I have demonstrated below (not the actual program this just makes the problem clear.) Anyway I need to change the properties of an object in another method but I don't want to define the properties of pen in another class. I would assume this is super simple and that I have just made a dumb mistake so how would i go about doing this?

```
public class Test {

    pen PEN = new pen();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(colouredPen(PEN).colour);
    }

    static Object pen() {
        String colour;
        return pen();
    }

    static Object colouredPen(Object pen) {
        pen.colour = "red";
        return pen;
    }
}
```

I do know you can just do this but was wondering if you had to.

```
public class Test {

    static pen PEN = new pen();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        colouredPen();
        System.out.println(PEN.colour);
    }

    static void colouredPen() {
    PEN.colour = "red"; 
    }
}

class pen {
    String colour;
}
```

Comment: I think you need a `Pen` class.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: Can't say I understand what you want. You wanna create a new type of object and access/mutate it's properties without defining another class?

Comment: `pen()` method will cleary resulted to stackoverflow

Comment: Wow.. is that java? Anyway the pen() method is recursive.

Comment: So it is impossible to define a new object without creating a separate class just for that?

Comment: Java has strong typing. Everything must have a declaration.

Comment: So even if I use a try catch when setting the colour there will be no way of doing this? I guess that you aren't allowed to declare objects inside methods.

Comment: You create new types by defining new classes. Think of "class" in the context of games: you have a Warrior class and a Mage class. They are different types of fighters you can choose. Classes in programming specify different types of objects. To create a new type, you need a new class. What is your primary goal? Look into [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you're falling victim to it

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no you cannot define objects in methods.

Comment: Actually, you can declare classes in a method. You can also create objects in a method. Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: So it can be done after all? Could you provide an example? Because most people seemed to imply yhere was no way of doing this.

Comment: Test it yourself: `void method() { class Test { } }`